# How to manage stdin and out of a process during runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to control a child process through the subprocess module.

I'm trying to read from the Minecraft bedrock server software using its stdout. However, when I write to the stdin it goes through but when I read from the stdout afterwards it is blocked.

```
import subprocess as sp
proc = sp.Popen([r"C:\Users\jbloo\Documents\VSCode\Python\bedrock-server-1.12.1.1\bedrock_server.exe"], 
stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT, stdin=sp.PIPE,  universal_newlines=True)
with proc:
    while True:
        # print("Trying to communicate")
        output = proc.stdout.readline().strip()
        print(output)
        if "Server started." in output:
            break
    while True:
        command = input("Command: ", ) + "\n"
        # command  = bytes(command, "utf-8")
        proc.stdin.write(command)
        print("Wrote")
        print(proc.stdout.readline())
```

I have tried many of the other solutions but I can't seem to get it.

this is the end of the terminal out.

```
[2019-10-17 01:22:04 INFO] IPv4 supported, port: 19132
[2019-10-17 01:22:04 INFO] IPv6 supported, port: 19133
[2019-10-17 01:22:05 INFO] IPv4 supported, port: 54072
[2019-10-17 01:22:05 INFO] IPv6 supported, port: 54073
[2019-10-17 01:22:05 INFO] Server started.
Command: sdf
Wrote
```

The STDOUT won't read. It is just blocked!

Answer (score 1):

readline is a blocking call. it reads until newline or EOF.

I am not sure, But issue is due to the child processnot writing anything to the Stdout after you have sent the command. hence parent process is waiting at readline function.